# Counting how many objects belong to a parent parent in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Basically I have 3 different models

```
class Zone < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :providers
end

class Provider < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :referrals 
  belongs_to :zone
end

class Referrals < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :provider
end
```

Referrals belong to Providers which then belongs to a Zone. Now the problem im having is counting how many referrals from a zone?

this is the erb tag I tried

```
    <% @zones.each do |z| %>
      <li style="color: green">
        <%= link_to z.name, z %>
        <% z.providers.each do |p| %>
          <%= p.referrals.count %> 
        <% end %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
```

But that counts the referrals from each provider and displays it. I want it to just show the total only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Zone < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :providers
  has_many :referrals, through: :providers
end
```

This will let you do...

```
z.referrals.count
```